# Как разбить строку на многомерный массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Имею строки вида:

> [["Bulk","550","rub/m3"],["Bulk","1000","rub/t"]]

Как ее разщбить на многомерный массив, чтобы в дальнейшем я смог обратиться к ней по нужному индексу?